# problem with parsing data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, parsing

hi folks i am parsing a xml file using NSXmlParser class.i am sending path exactly and i can able to see the parsing in my simulator upto now i got what i expected.Now i installed the same code and same data of(xml file) into the device and again i checked the data its working well.

My Problem:After disconnecting the the device from my xcode again i am trying to parse the data same as above this time it is not working.

MyQuestion: I know simulator is case in sensitive and device(ipad) is case sensitive so while i installed through the xcode then its working even in the device but after disconnecting it is not working.can any one please give me your idea about this situation.I cross checked with all the code there is no problem.Your suggestion is more important for me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your xml file is copied into bundle resources. Goto 'Targets' select/right-click your target and expand 'Copy Bundle Resources', if your file is not there, +/drag-drop it. Hope it works :)

Comment: Thanks for your replay.its there thats way it is getting parsing while i am connecting device to my IDE

Comment: then check if its in the project folder or not. You might have dragged it but not checked the 'copy to project' thing. Just giving suggestions here. Never experienced anything like this

Comment: thanks for your suggestion its there.I too never faced this type of situation

Comment: try putting an alert in a parser delegate method to check if its getting called or not

Comment: +1 thanks for your suggestion its getting parse.I think problem is some other i ll try to fix.